# How to get 'tooltip' information from two separate layers in Vega-Lite charts

Tags: vega-lite

Here is an [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUAotEYgD6RjxTTQAG1QMQIXEHm1kajGiAWpIWi1+JImvwmpJgk1BqgRnzpCNJAAtXTeabqHBHdSYTTaTkAAgAUkgFArGczdAAJVWGMh-BRIQyReUtbY7cmUxrM1Q4+kallMjlcnkCgVSEai1TiwSS6UaemK3xwJjqplm1Q6g76-ZGk3oTWI5SWwRU1BLJa2unaB2slbO7m8-kjD0isVsCU0KVpNQB+WSBUAWSQNjDmsjupjhuNqRAGfNyZAFNTjRWKyzmHt4dZgwLruLgs95cr1dAMrl6EVAEEcK2HdrOwa472x+aALoTpDozAEwx4s2oMlDq1oG20yc56eSfOcwtuktCqKFrPiO1ITlOzIznORaSO6gHbIOw5pgAnJm74QY6YjQf+i5lsBSGjuO6GfpBkhLNhC6lkBZ5IhkoS2KS2KoigNaGgg9I4le+KEmaSIxKqECOAECCMSAUAQh4GQfugADkABqATXIICoFJkTB0BAMm6FepjbBeIDIDYADW0rhPSwjWLoXg2GwRlwN0RgmKgNLWbZ9J-IcSL7GYPwKK4Nb3DWzjZIc6AEWKZnaAAjgwqoyqiNCkNpyRYrWsr0gAkgotzGnkURJiAiT+uxACqCh0No9Etgg5gwHaujBYIoXEd6dboMlKRHB0OSphAMDRLE8S1lARlTAweRoGIBVmDMdhBS8TW6ao0AQo02I+JYSiPiACk2Dg0wqWpGkgPpNiqmQjQkiAHknXxbU6IiwGcUcbEccx163kSCFqGdcJCYEoniYIknZrJWrTKECpRnqR49lpCS9lAemqIZJk1pgkXoBZWjLTEbkOcY-XOV52VsL5-mgIFoCNc14XepjIAxXFdAJUlCQpf66XaFlOWvPlSJFejNCleVbwgFVgS1fVqg09o0tpRuOjs51Nbdb4vVEzEcStSNY0TagU1Iq5dlHCtG6gL9F2kiAMb7LoTCgTRMsLc1SO7BdByc4rA5qBWvpVkcsvoD6fqPYOz2sUg7Fy+93F3sSSKo6ZETaLEcqqDNszvBkI3fd5ZNWBThXFXAZUVegEs1XkdXZq1XPtUibDXLcGNHA4PyAltKZpo8IDXGdInoCCpB2KoiA4K3qCOBC6JIuFfJ8X7frzSF2ghwHRt43ZBNOd3jRNJvNl2QAIleRN76SmZiDRSL91HqRPq9wJsCPVnZP8bxrgz+1WPkzshQ-Yi+lrAtkiG8LWQ0gToBqp4OAL8GIZ00C2bQMD0RsAYPkRENEaJAA).

I have a Vega-Lite chart with two layers of data being rendered, and I would like to have both 'displayed' in the tooltip information.

I have tried adding 'tooltip' information to both datasets, but the tooltip layer only picks a single dataset.

I also tried just adding two tooltip layers, one for each dataset, but that failed spectacularly. :)

And I tried 'adding' the tooltip information from one dataset to the other, which also did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a solution](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUAotEYgD6RjxTTQAG1QMQIXEHm1kajGiAWpIWi1+JImvwmpJgk1BqgRnzpCNJAAtbbKcmUxrM1Q4+mM5mslmc7m8-kjKQjUU7CWCKmoJZLGV07TylmSFYcrk8gUCjUisU6vUrFZGzByplmwaWlU29VCrUAXVdSHRmAJhjxLVJjqlNNlJo9rItyutasFmodIApusarVd7oVki9KdVklt-sz2b1AE5DbS3QnC2Jvamy36M9qs5K0M7842zUsW6Xyx2g-WQ-jCSto12c9S++hTaz2SXfen7e0rPSABLTUIAAm3SAOZD+CiQhkile7qGl9YLZqVVuH7Y3IGE1m0u8EB6PJ7PF5Xp2VaNAaC4Mom5pDmudqipun7oN+v7HoYp77IBUTATevb3v2rLFs+MEVvBO57oeKFoeel6YeKs56ne8aLpByaEWmsHlFu2gAGoBDg0z7gUmRMHQNExvOuFMYWBE+mxxHvpx6A8TYfGCAJQkidec6oLW4FLpIzarrJGYkdxvH8YJTDCZimlOi6EkQYWg6GW265wfJCEgEpKlqZZGlbAGSIZKEtgzjiKBpCA54IPSYWhuGkZimoNjHhAjgBAgM5QBCHgZA26AAOReRCPlWRA+W6CGpjbGOyA2AA1kcmDhPSH5aKoXg2GwdVwN0RgmLe7UxF19J-IcSL7GYPwKK4EX3BFzjZIc6AgboTURNoACODDHuoFjqKQFXJFiagaPSACSCi3JeeSYUiiSNTQ0UAKoKHQ2jBUggTmDA8aqAtghLbhqi7Zo2iHSkRwdDkuoQDA0SxPEJ1QHVUwMHkaBiIiqhmDMdjzS8ANVe1WWgxFhg+JYSioCSnlmapFmlSAY7JdNjQ06NTNIiD9LbFj2KouFoBRTFAtxYSxJcyzqXpZl2UMLl9L5Uh5H-uh1HlQkqQgFA1WqLVDURWtLWcYNnXdb1xhw7e42XWwU0zaAc2gP9gMrcDzWbdteR0KiNAHQkR0PZgpMgBdV2vLdqj3Ybj1wC9b3oB9X15D9xp-QTgO-Sdwc8wHEMRVDvgw1bMRxMDNDI6j6OoJjSIdcNRzQBCjSgCzZBsyAaH7LoTBzgF6eLUT757AcQch7zwNsNM6g4EcLvaN4080LPiKdmFRzC9osWThG06SylaWBDOOB+6U2itboK3Ld2qinmwDA4Ewc00-GAU1Z9BsgLEoOqBNdtWA7EA0dnYZy3mnNQHt0BugQHxZKkIkRsGuLcJqRwHA-EBFTMSfJKB2WuMlDK6AQSkDsL-GBKDUCOAhOiJEV9JBcynoIGeM556ITIn+VCAFqKrUgSALaO0fb7S0J2FhtNlLmXUtZd2610B8O9ntP2Qj+4gDwUgBAqQySRVUfSIhIV2rZH+G8UARttB8SsPkAeAN1G4THNYT6kQ3il0RkCdACB77ojYMQ+wmhPraFcZ4OA998iIjflsIAA) based on your provided example that works for a combined dataset. This solution is based on the "Multi Series Line Chart with Tooltip" from the Online Editor ([link](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip.html)).

For the combined dataset, there is a new attribute that denotes which line the data corresponds to (e.g., `{"value": 12, "date": "2022-01-10T14:00:00.000Z", "line": "Holy Handgrenades"}`; this new attribute is then used as part of the tooltip specification in the new layer (e.g., `"tooltip": [{"field": "Holy Handgrenades", "type": "quantitative"}, ...]` in combination with the layer transform that ensures that the data is in the right format: `"transform": [{"pivot": "line", "value": "value", "groupby": ["date"]}]`. The resulting tooltip would look like this:

[image: default tooltip showing value for both lines]

Note also that with the combined dataset, it is possible to draw the two lines in the same layer as in [this version of the provided example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWI7ECFxVIAbVAGMEcQebWRqMaIBakhaLX4kia-CakmCTUGqBGrOkI0kAC1ylYyQAJaahAAE-KQBzIfwUSEMkW2yjxmMaVNUKMwZIpVJp1IZTJZbJGUhGPPafO0gsEIrFEqlMrlO0VBMaSyWqtJ2k11MkK3pjOZ7PZRu5vOs5qFovFhkl+ztUQdIHxhNQKxWbvVHspXsGvr1AcNnJNIGEofQFqtkej0tlcYVCaVaBVJPT6E9NJ9uv9Bo5xpDZIAagEcNNhQVMkw6DXHUnWmmNZmadmO-rJIGC73tAObEPBCOxxP5VPGgBOV1NudayRiHOdlf5numksgTfb3dMceYSd1p1oFOzjMXpZr2XVd7yLM10GfYdRzffctgAXSRDJQlsNBcRAZAbAAayOTBwjJYstFULwbDYTC4G6IwTFQFokX2MwfgUVw0hAe5mOcbJDnQRNCLUPDtAARwYcV1AsdRSF0JIUhwjQyQASQUW5ZTyOMkUSaSEDgABVBQ6G0ZCkECcwYDVHj2METiz10ETNG0CTklSdJxhyAkIBgaJYniNQaCgTCpgYPI0DERFVDMGY7DYl5zO0AjdGgCFGlAQwfEsJRUGxJ9BygvcP10MsIxtGNqxAODVBscUyEadK-kOVRo32YqkWssltmC0AYnFCBHACBBUNAHAaGIUporNVRuO0MbapIhgcCYVj0pMhqSvQgzsPQWIbNUOi2AYpjQDUiKOO0BbVFwiJtHVBAhzKyEkTYa5blwo4HB+QFUsPNBpFTEBrjKnr0BBUg7E2y7HtQRwIQgOAkTG1lGrYaZ1BwXqQDMiy8utKNbSKk6+PQQThLoVEBq0eNUY3TKd2g98ohxs68aEvJCbEkmENUH6kAQHFQGlDTgTYQHYuyf43ja3HvrYKx8lUVGcUspbrAMyI3hiOInlS9C2E8OB+ZQkLNAM7QEE1yHNfyREEIQoA).

**UPDATE - Removing missing values from the tooltip**

In the comments below, @GregBartlett asked about updating the tooltip to remove missing values rather than showing a zero. There are two options for how to approach this: (1) impute NaN rather than zero or (2) create a custom tooltip (with less styling).

*(1) Impute NaN rather than zero*

The impute transform ([link](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/impute.html)) allows you to add new data entries that are otherwise missing from the dataset. In this case, we could use the line `{"impute": "value", "key": "date", "value": "N/A", "groupby": ["line"]},` before the `pivot` transform in the example above. [Here is a link to this solution in the Online editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWI7ECFxVIAbVAGMEcQebWRqMaIBakhaLX4kia-CakmCTUGqBGrOkI0kAC1ylYyQAJaahAAE-KQBzIfwUSEMkW2yjxmMaVNUKMwZIpVJp1IZTJZbJGUhGPPafO0gsEIrFEqlMrlO0VBMaSyWqtJ2k11MkK3pjOZ7PZRu5vOs5qFovFhkl+ztUQdIHxhNQKxWbvVHspXsGvr1AcNnJNIGEofQFqtkej0tlcYVCaVaBVJPT6E9NJ9uv9Bo5xpDZIAagEcNNhQVMkw6DXHUnWmmNZmadmO-rJIGC73tAObEPBCOxxP5VPGgBOV1NudayRiHOdlf5numksgTfb3dMceYSd1p1oFOzjMXpZr2XVd7yLM10GfYdRzffctgAXSRDJQlsNBcRAZAbAAayOTBwjJYstFULwbDYTC4G6IwTFQFokX2MwfgUVw0hAe5mOcbJDnQRNCLUPDtAARwYcV1AsdRSF0JIUhwjQyQASQUW5ZTyOMkUSaSEDgABVBQ6G0ZCkECcwYDVHj2METiz10ETNG0CTklSdJxhyAkIBgaJYniNQaCgTCpgYPI0DERFVDMGY7DYl5zO0AjdGgCFGlAQwfEsJRUGxJ9BygvcP10MsIxtGNqxAODVBscUyEadK-kOVRo32YqkWssltmC0AYnFCBHACBBUNAGgEBwBhmy-QlVDI1jLNUbjtAAOQIABBXRJTYBgcCYVj0pihDaxwGhiFKaKzSm+suPrWqSNW9bUMshCSvQgzsPQWIbNUOi2AYpjQDUiKOO0EyrL49B1QGgIIXlEA2GuW5cKOBwfkBVLDzQaRUxAa4yp69AQVIOxXoGmHUEcCEIDgJFptZRq2GmdQcF6kAzIsvLrSjW0itUXCIgEoS8joVE9q0eMGY3TKd2g98onZwGQEE4TebEgXtrRgykAQHFQGlDTgTYHHYuyf43jaqWhysfJVAZnEbtUawDMiN4YjiJ5UvQlaSe1lCQs0AztAQF24BW-JEVurYgA) As the data now includes an "N/A" string value, the tooltip would now look like this:

[image: default tooltip using NaN for missing values]

*(2) Create a custom tooltip with less styling*

In order to have a version that simply does not include the values when they are missing, one approach is to use a `calculate` transform ([link](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html)) to create a custom field using an `if` expression ([link](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#control-flow-functions)) to determine the condition: `"transform": [{"calculate": "datum['Holy Handgrenades'] > 0 ? (datum['Vorpol Rabbits'] > 0 ? 'Holy Handgrenades:' + datum['Holy Handgrenades'] + ', Vorpol Rabbits:' + datum['Vorpol Rabbits'] : 'Holy Handgrenades:' + datum['Holy Handgrenades']) : 'Vorpol Rabbits:' + datum['Vorpol Rabbits']", "as": "tooltip"}],`. [Here is a link to this solution in the Online editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUDECFxVIAbWxuMarVUKMwjRALUkLRa-EkTX4TUkwSag1QIw50hGkgAWuUrJSABLTUIAAiFSAOZD+CiQhki22URMEcTQtLJqMp1Np9LpzNZ7M5IykI357UF2hFgnFkulsvlip2KrVqCWS01FO0OrpkhWTJZbK5XNNfIF1itoolUsMMv2jqizpAONVjRWK092ppvsGAcNwZNPPNIGEEfQ1ttMbjcoVieVyeJ6rayK13uz9P9BqDxu5ZvDlIAagEcNMxQVMkw6HWXSTm+Ss7rJLmu0bJCGi-3tEObCPBGOJ1OlTO0ABOD0tr3oH30sR57trwt9i1lkDb3f7piTzFHhuptDpzM20XJY71XdcnxLS10DfUdx0-Q8tgAXVUCkvDQQkLwXX1GRXAtezDVQK2je141rB4WiTecgN9fVAzAx8CJAIi7VjB0yNQWlKNbK92z9UC8NDYtmKrNjFTdc8YL3OCv1STj6yonjF2XOiBI3QioxY6sE3-DNX2HWCD2-ZoKPk7iqV429cJ7QTdEkj8ZNPJYuMvczgP46y1L0ncDPgoz0yQpEMlCWx0NAckUDSEA5QQSkUzxJUQGQGwAGsjkwcJKVLLRVC8Gw2GSuBuiMEwOKRfYzB+BRXEi+5IucbJDnQOLsrUDLtAARwYKV1AsdRSF0JIUjSjRKQASQUW4FTyRMkUSYaYoAVQUOhtGCpBAnMGAqNUerBEazDdB6zRtAG5IsRLcYclVCAYGiWJ4jUGgoGSqYGDyNAxERVQzBmOw6pePbtCy3RoAhRowp8SwlFQfEvPfaTD3Um1iNY0jFWQkAbClMhGlhv5DlUON9hARCkSOylti+sLUQi0BospVD8jJrG4UcAIEFCkAoAhDwMhc8kYXxAByYSSJrSIhcQsUAD4xUkMUAH4xQACgFhBhbshHMUlmW5cVsURY0kS0fwIWxQAajFNXhdF1HxYgHXLaF5QxU1wzTYtq3UUFoW3d8h2pdQA3ba02tUDNy3rcN5HNNEgOAEoxSD339Kk93w89qO-ZkyWBtSNQ2GmdQcG2DGktS9BYmO1RyrYSrqtAOb-oa7RttaiJtApBARyxyEkTYa5bnSo4HB+QFoePDlKF064sY59AQVIOwa+74fUEcCF0SRZq0EkMnC8EYujl2-bvCLmgS6+kBZ6QBACTp2-KUXkKcuyf43lAdKO-QEcrHyHaAaGAJAdDG1h1qRDeDEOITxoaJTYJ4OAbAl72E0OtbQCB4HongUzAKpMgA) The resulting tooltip would look like this:

[image: custom tooltip showing one value]
[image: custom tooltip showing two values]

Comment: Thank you for your great answers! :)

I think there would only be 1 tweak that would be good to have.

When there is no data for one of the datasets, these examples show a value of '0'.  Which isn't entirely correct.

Can this be done so that when there is no data, there just isn't an entry in the tooltip?

Comment: @GregBartlett Interesting question and great point; I am not sure if there is a way to do exactly what you're asking (perhaps that would be worthy of a separate question), but perhaps a workaround would be to `impute` the missing data as "N\A" which would show "NaN" instead of 0 in the tooltip. For example, you can include the following before the `pivot` transform: `{"impute": "value", "key": "date", "value": "N/A", "groupby": ["line"]},`

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply compute a new tooltip string to show/hide the particular elements use a `calculate` transform, but unfortunately the formatting in this case is less clean than the default, multi-row tooltip. Here is the transform: `"transform": [{"calculate": "datum['Holy Handgrenades'] > 0 ? (datum['Vorpol Rabbits'] > 0 ? 'Holy Handgrenades:' + datum['Holy Handgrenades'] + ', Vorpol Rabbits:' + datum['Vorpol Rabbits'] : 'Holy Handgrenades:' + datum['Holy Handgrenades']) : 'Vorpol Rabbits:' + datum['Vorpol Rabbits']", "as": "tooltip"}],`

Comment: When I tried your second solution I get both tooltip entries for all dates with data and `NaN` for all of the datums/values.

Comment: For the second one, you'll also need to change the tooltip line to `"tooltip": {"field": "tooltip"}`. I will update my answer above to include sample links for these two solutions as well.

Comment: Thank you @sabine, I am going with your #2.

The less styling is annoying, can't get a line break in there.  But the information for UX is better.

Comment: I commented too soon. After playing around adding a new dataset, I ended up going that path.  Here is my [solution](https://shorturl.at/enJVW)